# Django TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Tags: python, django, post

Background: I need to do a POST request to add data to my program.

I'm currently using advanced REST client to simulate the data packet that will be send by a arduino.
it is currently sending this as a POST request:

```
{"cellVoltageLow":28,"cellVoltageHigh":415,"cellVoltageAvg":415,
  "cellTempMin":5,"cellTempMax":15,"cellTempAvg":10,"stateOfCharge":50,
    "errorBitmap":0,"batteryVoltageIn":420,"motorAmp":200,"usageAmp":210,
      "auxAmp":10,"rpmMotor":1000,"uiState":0,"chargingStatus":1,
        "motorTemp":15,"inverterTemp":30,"inletTemp":5,"ambientTemp":5,
          "chargingAmp":10,"chargingVoltage":420,"apsVoltage":42,
            "maxAmpsInCharge":10,"bmsErrorValue":0,"energyDriveAH":1000,
              "energyRegenAH":100,"energyChargeAH":10,"energyDischargeAH":10,
                "energyDriveWH":1000,"energyRegenWH":10,"energyChargeWH":2300,
                  "energyDischargeWH":23000,"drivenDistanceCM":100000,
                    "chargedEnergyWH":1000,"returnedEnergyWH":10000,
                      "connectedTimeSec":100,"driveTimeSec":240}
```

if i post this to this class (csrf is disabled)

```
def Voltage(request):
    global Voltage

    if request.method == 'POST':

        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        Voltage.cellVoltageLow = data["cellVoltageLow"]
        Voltage.cellVoltageAvg = data["cellVoltageAvg"]
        Voltage.cellVoltageHigh = data["cellVoltageHigh"]
        Voltage.batteryVoltageIn = data["batteryVoltageIn"]
        Voltage.chargingVoltage = data["chargingVoltage"]
        Voltage.apsVoltage = data["apsVoltage"]


        print("got ur message" + str(request.body))

        return HttpResponse("OK")

    if request.method == 'GET':

        return HttpResponse('{ "cellVoltageLow":' + str(Voltage.cellVoltageLow)
                            + '{ "cellVoltageAvg":' + str(Voltage.cellVoltageAvg)
                            + '{ "cellVoltageHigh":' + str(Voltage.cellVoltageHigh)
                            + '{ "batteryVoltageIn":' + str(Voltage.batteryVoltageIn)
                            + '{ "chargingVoltage":' + str(Voltage.chargingVoltage)
                            + '{ "apsVoltage":' + str(Voltage.apsVoltage)
                            +  ' }' )

    else:

        return HttpResponse ('Not allowed')

class Voltage:
    cellVoltageLow = 0;
    cellVoltageAvg = 0;
    cellVoltageHigh = 0;
    batteryVoltageIn = 0;
    chargingVoltage = 0;
    apsVoltage = 0;
```

Then i get the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

I am a noob on python so please give me an extended explanation about whats wrong.

EDIT:
i replaced the clashing name of function and class. I am also the wrong way to create JSON strings because I don't have the knowledge to create a JSON string with the correct code.

I also still get the internal error 500

```
def voltage(request):
    global voltage

    if request.method == 'POST':

        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        Voltage.cellVoltageLow = data["cellVoltageLow"]
        Voltage.cellVoltageAvg = data["cellVoltageAvg"]
        Voltage.cellVoltageHigh = data["cellVoltageHigh"]
        Voltage.batteryVoltageIn = data["batteryVoltageIn"]
        Voltage.chargingVoltage = data["chargingVoltage"]
        Voltage.apsVoltage = data["apsVoltage"]


        print("got ur message" + str(request.body))

        return HttpResponse("OK")

    if request.method == 'GET':

        return HttpResponse('{ "cellVoltageLow":' + str(Voltage.cellVoltageLow)
                            + '{ "cellVoltageAvg":' + str(Voltage.cellVoltageAvg)
                            + '{ "cellVoltageHigh":' + str(Voltage.cellVoltageHigh)
                            + '{ "batteryVoltageIn":' + str(Voltage.batteryVoltageIn)
                            + '{ "chargingVoltage":' + str(Voltage.chargingVoltage)
                            + '{ "apsVoltage":' + str(Voltage.apsVoltage)
                            +  ' }' )

    else:

        return HttpResponse ('Not allowed')

class Voltage:
    cellVoltageLow = 0;
    cellVoltageAvg = 0;
    cellVoltageHigh = 0;
    batteryVoltageIn = 0;
    chargingVoltage = 0;
    apsVoltage = 0;
```

EDIT: I fixed it with the help of @MosesKoledoye reply. The answer was in the Voltage.

i changed my code to

```
def voltage(request):
    global voltage
    if request.method == 'POST':

        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        Voltage.cellVoltageLow = data["cellVoltageLow"]
        Voltage.cellVoltageAvg = data["cellVoltageAvg"]
        Voltage.cellVoltageHigh = data["cellVoltageHigh"]
        Voltage.batteryVoltageIn = data["batteryVoltageIn"]
        Voltage.chargingVoltage = data["chargingVoltage"]
        Voltage.apsVoltage = data["apsVoltage"]

        print("got ur message" + str(request.body))

        return HttpResponse("OK")

    if request.method == 'GET':

        return HttpResponse('{ "cellVoltageLow":' + str(Voltage.cellVoltageLow)
                            + '{ "cellVoltageAvg":' + str(Voltage.cellVoltageAvg)
                            + '{ "cellVoltageHigh":' + str(Voltage.cellVoltageHigh)
                            + '{ "batteryVoltageIn":' + str(Voltage.batteryVoltageIn)
                            + '{ "chargingVoltage":' + str(Voltage.chargingVoltage)
                            + '{ "apsVoltage":' + str(Voltage.apsVoltage)
                            +  ' }' )

    else:

        return HttpResponse ('Not allowed')

class Voltage:
    cellVoltageLow = 0;
    cellVoltageAvg = 0;
    cellVoltageHigh = 0;
    batteryVoltageIn = 0;
    chargingVoltage = 0;
    apsVoltage = 0;
```

and then in urls.py i changed the Voltage to voltage

```
    url(r'^voltage/', views.Voltage, name='Voltage'),
to
    url(r'^voltage/', views.voltage, name='Voltage'),
```

thank you for your help, I get an 200 OK as it is supposed to be.
thank you for all the responses.

Comment: The function and class should not share the same the name `Voltage`

Comment: Code reviewy rather than an answer but you should really use the `json` module to build JSON rather than string methods.

Comment: I was able to fix it. Thank you @MosesKoledoye

Comment: BTW: I also got the object() takes no parameters error, and landed here when I searched.  But the reason I got the error was that I had forgotten to derive the serializer from serializers.ModelSerializer -- just something else to check...

Answer (score 0):

You should not declare a global variable. This is not the right way to create objects in Django.

Instead, just initialise and declare the object after the data is ready to be stored.

```
if request.method == "POST":
   data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
   new_voltage = Voltage.objects.create()
   new_voltage.cellVoltageLow = data["cellVoltageLow"]
   ... # Store other data too
   new_voltage.save()
```

Refer to documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects

Comment: If this would fix the error i am willing to try to do this but it looks alot simpler to create a global variable and since i never got any lessions to code i'd rather stick with global variables.

I will still try to change my code to the above example.

Comment: I "think" that i implemented it but it doesnt solve the 500 error.

Comment: @ronaldberkhout Global variables may seem convenient at first, but in a concurrent environment such as Django, you will soon start encountering seemingly random bugs that require a great deal of effort to debug, let alone to fix. Don't use global variables.

Comment: @knbk I'll keep that in mind for my next project. Sadly the code is almost done except this error...